# What's the name of this function property - separable?

Tags: functions

What's it called when $g(x,y,z)$ can be expressed $g_x(x) + g_y(y) + g_z(z)$ for some function in $N$ dimensions in general?

I'm reading a paper and they seem to be calling this property "separable". But at least one definition of a [separable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186673/separable-and-non-separable-function) is: $g$ separable if $g(x,y,z) = g_x(x)g_y(y)g_z(z)$.

Comment: I think decomposable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I call it  **completely additively separable functions** as stated in [wikipedia page of additively separable functions](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Additively_separable_function)

Suppose $F$ is a function of $n$ variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$. We say $F$ is **completely additively separable** if there exist functions $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n$, each a function of one variable, such that:

$$F(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i) $$

Notice that there is also a  [multiplicative version](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicatively_separable_function).

Suppose $G$ is a function of $n$ variables $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$. We say $G$ is **completely multiplicatively separable** if there exist functions $g_1, g_2, \ldots, g_n$, each a function of one variable, such that:

$$G(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n g_i(x_i) $$